# Installing PDO extension for MySQL on Mac OS X Server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to keep the PHP / MySQL combo as 'stock vanilla' as possible but would like to install the PDO driver for MySQL. How can I do this on 10.5?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was forced to install a different version of PHP from [entropy.ch](http://www.entropy.ch). I'm still having some trouble with the php CLI, but otherwise it works fine.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).

Hope that helps,

Ross

Comment: MAMP is good. I use it all day every day. Comes with PDO etc. Very easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can [compile the extensions separately](http://blog.elance.at/2009/09/15/adding_php_extensions_under_mac_os_x_10_6.html) and simply link to them in your php.ini file. Actually very easy to do.